# Is data returned by std::string::c_str() still valid after the string is moved?

Tags: c++, move-semantics, stdstring

Let's say I have a function that sends `const char *` data asynchronously, and invokes a callback when data is sent or an error happens (I omitted error handling as irrelevant to the question):

```
void sendData( const char *data, std::function<void()> );
```

So, until the callback is invoked, I have to maintain the data passed to the function as valid.

One solution is to pass the result of `std::string::c_str()` and move this string into the callback:

```
 void send( std::string str )
 {
     auto data = str.c_str();
     sendData( data, [st=std::move(str)]() {} );
 }
```

So, `str` should be moved into the lambda, and when it is invoked, it should destroy the string at the end.

Of course, I can move the original string to a `std::unique_ptr<std::string>` and then move that pointer into the lambda, but this code is simpler.

So, is it safe to do so?

Comment: No, it is not safe. The pointer returned by `c_str()` may well be invalidated by the move (e.g. in case of small string optimization). Also, it's possible that the second argument (the lambda) is constructed first, and you are calling `c_str()` on an object that has already been moved from.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik good point for order of evaluation, modified example to avoid that

Comment: The small string optimization problem still stands. `str.c_str()` may be a pointer to a buffer within `str` object, and will of course become dangling when `str` is destroyed.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik sure, just want to avoid answers that irrelevant to subj so removed that ambiguity.

Comment: Besides, the lambda itself will be copied into `std::function`, `string` member and all. The string will get copied anyway, leaving the original pointer dangling. The lambda that will eventually run is not the same object created in `send`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik you are right `std::function` requires lambda to be copied so I cannot even use `std::unique_ptr` only `std::shared_ptr` in this case. Damn.

Comment: So looks like my question splits into 2, about `c_str()` after move and moving lambda into `std::function`. (and second is already answered on SO)

Comment: Rather than a lambda, you may wish to define an explicit named class to act as the callback. This class could then implement the desired lifetime management semantics. You could also have it expose the `char*` that it itself manages (via a `std::string` member or otherwise) rather than relying on `str.c_str()` surviving long enough.

Comment: What would Rust do?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik unfortunately `sendData` is provided by a library so modifying it would be impractical. I can use `std::shared` ptr or store the string in a container and erase it afterwards. This solution just looked very simple. Oh well.

Comment: You don't need to modify `sendData`. `std::function` is not limited to wrapping lambdas, it can wrap any callable object. You can write your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to understand that the moved-from and moved-to objects are two distinct objects. They are not one object that, due to some mysterious process, disappears in one place and reappears somewhere else. That's not what a move is.

A moved-from object still exists, and when it goes out of scope and gets destroyed its destructor gets invoked normally.

The C++ standard itself does not really specify what exactly a move means. In your own classes you can define a move constructor and a move assignment operator to do anything. Including nothing. All that C++, the language itself, does for you is formally define the conditions that require a move constructor or a move assignment operator to be invoked. That's it. That's the C++ compiler's job: invoke the constructor or the assignment operator when they are qualified to do so. The scant explanation of what a move actually is, once they are invoked, is defined in the C++ standard as an assertion that: for classes defined in a C++ library a move leaves the moved-from object in some "valid but unspecified state".

The pointer returned from `c_str()` is owned by its `std::string`. It is valid only until its owning object is modified in any way. Turning this object into some "valid but unspecified state" would do the trick. The pointer from `c_str()` is no longer valid. The fact that the `std::string` was moved somewhere else is immaterial and does not change that. There's nothing in the C++ standard's specification of `c_str()`'s semantics that further qualifies its requirements with respect to moved objects.